# How to add queryParams without routerLink Click in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routerlink

I wonder add queryParams to url without router.navigateByUrl or routerLink Click in angular

I did not try anything

add Query params to url

Comment: Pls, if you have specific requirements, add more info.  your question is quite generic.  is it a link in your own application you want to send / get data to or is it an external call to an API.  etc

Comment: In angular application, If you use router of angular frameWork, You will use 'Router' of @angular/router module

then, If I use routing in application, I will use add [routerLink] to template or execute router.navigateByUrl, But this method change browers url link,
I just add query params to url

Comment: I understand, but what is it really you want to achieve??  give us a **concrete** example of what you try to do. e.g. page A has X, want to go to page B and I want to transfer some data Z in a certain format. (or i want to trigger something)

Comment: This is not about http request.
In my web page, *ngIf is depends on router params.

For example
https://exampleUrl/sign/loginUp=true => login pop up true
https://exampleUrl/sign/loginUp=false => register pop up true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add [queryParams] directive

```
<a routerLink="contact" [queryParams]="{first:fu,last:bar}" >
   Contact
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved use same routerLink

```html
<div [routerLink]="'/some'" [queryParams]="{s: 'true'}" ></div>
<div [routerLink]="'/some'" [queryParams]="{s: 'false'}" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
updateQueryParams(queryParams: Params) {
    this.router.navigate([], {
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
        queryParams,
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    });
}
```